# How to add a sitenames in the dropdown filter of an Experience Analytics in Sitecore 9.0.1

Tags: sxa, experience-analytics

I am using Sitecore 9.0.1 with SXA 1.7. I want to show the list of Sitenames inside the dropdown filter of an Experience Analytics . How can i achieve this?  By default it is showing All sites and Websites as the values inside the dropdown.

[image]

I want to show my sites in sitecore like the below screenshot which is taken from sitecore documentation [filter-an-experience-analytics-report.html](https://doc.sitecore.com/en/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/filter-an-experience-analytics-report.html) in my sitecore Experience Analytics Dashboard.

[image]
Thanks

Comment: If your site definition is ok i would check if xconnect collects any data for any of your sites and analytics is tracking them. This dropdown is usually automatically populated.

Answer (score 1):

That is not possible out of the box or configurable. SXA is not modifying the Experience Analytics dashboard.

Comment: By default the sitenames should come or is this the default behavior (which shows only website and all sites as values in the dropdown)? @Dawid Rutkowski

Comment: @Vinaya I don't know what is this drop-down and what is its default behaviour. This is not an SXA dialog.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check the `<sites>` tag in `showconfig.aspx` page, all websites are coming from there only?

[image]

Comment: Yes i have my sites listed in the showconfig.aspx but they are not appearing in the Experience analytics dashboard custom dropdown filter. Do i need to do something to display my sites in the dropdown? @Swati Gupta

Answer (score 0):

You need to add as many sites in your content tree. This name is picked from the site settings/SXA site Manager. You can right-click site grouping and add a new site.